# React routing not loading pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and I got stuck on a problem. I have started working on routing but its not working at all.

Code:

```
 import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import AllMeetupsPage from './pages/AllMeetups';
import NewMeetupsPage from './pages/NewMeetups';
import FavoritesPage from './pages/Favorites';


function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Route path = '/'>
          <AllMeetupsPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path = '/new-meetup'>
          <NewMeetupsPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path = '/favorites'>
          <FavoritesPage />
        </Route>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a blank screen even though the pages should load. Each page when open should only print one line just to see that I can see routing working however all I see is a blank space meaning its not working correctly.

You can view the full code here: https://github.com/Kroplewski-M/Routing

Comment: Can you show the part where you Router is created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can handle the routing in your index.js like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
   
      <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />} />
      <Route path="/new-meetup" element={<NewMeetupsPage />} />
      <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavoritesPage />} />
     
   
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your routes with `<BrowserRouter>` which is done already in `index` file which is fine. Next, Routes must be wrapped with `<Routes>` component as of `'react-router-dom'` latest version `v6`

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App(){
return (
<div>
  <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />} />
      <Route path="/new-meetup" element={<NewMeetupsPage />} /> 
  </Routes>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrapping the **route** under the **router** that's why your route is not working.

Here is the code.

```
 import {Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
 import AllMeetupsPage from './pages/AllMeetups';
 import NewMeetupsPage from './pages/NewMeetups';
 import FavoritesPage from './pages/Favorites';

 function App() {
   return (
       <div>
        <Router>
         <Route path = '/'>
           <AllMeetupsPage />
         </Route>
         <Route path = '/new-meetup'>
           <NewMeetupsPage />
         </Route>
         <Route path = '/favorites'>
           <FavoritesPage />
         </Route>
       </Router>
       </div>
   );
 }

 export default App;
```

I hope it will work.